# jquery-ui datepicker not appearing

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

im trying to do some code with jquery-ui
im wondering why it not working

my html code is

```
<a>open form</a>
<div></div>
```

my js code is

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url:"data.php",
            success:function(data){
                $("div").html(data);
            }
        });
    });
})
$(function(){
    $("input").on('click', function(){ $(this).datepicker(); });
});
```

and data.php contain

```
<input type="text" />
```

the result is, why the datepicker isn't appearing..?

and another problem is like this code

```
(document).ready(function(){
    $("a").click(function(){
        $("div").html("<input id='datepicker'><input id='tb_submit' type='submit' value='Submit' />");
    });
})
$(function(){
    $("body").on('click', "input#datepicker",function(){ $(this).datepicker(); });
    $("body").on('click','input#tb_submit',function(){$(this).button();})
});
```

the button should be clicked, then showed the true button.
do you have the solutions??

live code : http://jsfiddle.net/5Ps6P/28/

Comment: I don't get it, why should it appear? I do not see nay reference to datepicker anywhere....

Comment: Calling `$(this).datepicker()` doesn't make the datepicker appear, it just binds the datepicker to the element. The datepicker appears when you click on the element.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jquery-ui datepicker only appears after textbox focused second time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13393569/jquery-ui-datepicker-only-appears-after-textbox-focused-second-time)

Comment: pktangyue has solved my problem, thx for him

Answer (score 2):

Try this code:

```
$(function(){
    $(document).on('click', "input",function(){ $(this).datepicker(); });
});
```

Use this code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a").click(function(){
        $("div").html("<input id='datepicker'><input id='tb_submit' type='submit' value='Submit' />");
        $("input#datepicker").datepicker();
        $('input#tb_submit').button();
    });
})
```

You just need initialise it after adding it, and do not need bind click handler yourself.

Here is jsfiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/5Ps6P/30/

Comment: wow amazing, it usefull http://jsfiddle.net/5Ps6P/21/ but how about on submit, with many input in form..?

Comment: @JinSun do you mean `$(document).on('submit','form',function(){});`?

Comment: yes, its true..
but now i have another problem, its edited on my post

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your code to:

**Edit:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url:"data.php",
            success:function(data){
                var newInput = $(data);
                newInput.datepicker();
                $("div").html(newInput);
            }
        });
    });
})
```

Comment: yes its good, but when i use form with many input, it will more complicated while validating. isn't it?  http://jsfiddle.net/5Ps6P/10/

Comment: it will only call the datepicker method for each of the added elements, so, if your data.php, returns more than one input indeed, will not work correctly

Comment: yes thats right, im just testing with one input, but the result is make me disappointed. if i used many input, what a stress me..?

Comment: you can try the edited version, but I think it'll work similarlly

Answer (score 0):

```
This should work :
$(document).ready(function(){

$("a").click(function(){
    $("div").html("<input id='datepicker' type='text'>");
     $("#datepicker").datepicker();
});



 })
```

However i would suggest to make the input to be hidden and show it when link is clicked. This would ensure that your event is binded to the input when the DOC is created.

Comment: the $("#datepicker") is null if its inside the ready function since the input is not created until u click <a>

Answer (score -1):

Try using the live() jQuery function to listen to elements inserted after page loads.

```
// listen to clicks on input elements
$('input').live('click', function() {

  // apply datepicker to this input element
  $(this).datepicker();
});
```

Attach an event handler for all elements which match the current selector, **now and in the future**.
http://api.jquery.com/live/